# Are all final class immutable?

Tags: java, immutability

Are all final classes in Java immutable.
String and Integer both are final classes and both are immutable i beleive.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No - a final class means you cannot inherit from it. It has nothing to do with mutability. The following class is final yet mutable:

```
public final class FinalMutable {
  int value;
  public void setValue(int v) { value=v; }
  public int getValue() { return value; }
}
```

Comment: So in order to make the class immutable I have to scrap the setter() method out of the class and also make its instance variable (which in this case is "value") final.
Am i correct..??

Comment: Yes, you should scrap the setter and make "value" final.

Comment: To add to that, Rytmis make a good point below. If the value is a mutable object is your object really immutable? Best then make value private and change getValue to do a defensive copy.

Comment: So i believe this class is now an immutable one

final class immutability_test
{
 private final int value;  
 public immutability_test(int value)
 {
  this.value=value;
 }
 public final int getValue() 
 { 
  return value; 
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  System.out.println("The obtained value is    "+new immutability_test(4).getValue());
 }
}

Now i guees rytmi's point is also justified

Comment: I think, unless the value field is static, there is no way you can mutate this class. What is mutable is the object or objects created from it, am i right?

Comment: @returnFromException I'm afraid you're wrong - this class in this example can have different values over time (using its setValue() method), which makes is mutable

Comment: the methods are not static, so you are manipulating instance variables (int value). You cant do FinalMutable.setValue. You can only do finalModuleInstance.setValue(v). I think..

Answer (score 30):

No, final means the class can not be extended. It says nothing about mutability. For example:

```
final class MutInt {
   public int modifyMe;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

There is no keyword for immutability, it's more like a design pattern.

EDIT:
This means, there is no keyword, that makes a class immutable. To make a class immutable, you have to protect the internals by make them final or private.

The confusing thing is this: The final keyword has different meanings when used on a class then it has when used on a field/variable. The former means "this class can not be extended". The Second means "this variable (or reference) can not be changed".

Comment: there is the "final" keyword for fields and variables -- but then, it doesn't make the object immutable, just the reference.

Comment: @Rytmis: Yes, right but there is no keyowrd that makes a class immutable, like the java.lang.String is. I'll edit the answer to make this clearer.

Comment: And even more confusing, use of `final` on fields has also been overloaded with specific semantics in the Java Memory Model (since 1.5).

Answer (score 5):

Further to the other responses, if you look at the code for `java.lang.String` you'll see it contains a field: `hash`, which is **mutable** and is in fact computed and stored when `hashCode()` is called for the first time.

However, the class is still **immutable**: The `hash` field cannot be accessed directly or modified outside of the class.

Also, you may notice a common approach within the JDK is the implementation of immutable wrappers that can be used to expose an object's internal state without allowing it to be modified; e.g.

```
private final List<String> values;

public List<? get String> getValues() {
  return Collections.unmodifiableList(values);
}
```

Comment: And crucially for thread safety, the lazy assignment of the hash field is a *benign* data race. If it was not, two callers of hashCode(), in different threads, could see two different values.

Answer (score 5):

As has been said by the others before `final` does not make a class imuutable in Java though it plays a part in the immutability strategy. To obtain immutability you should follow the general guidlines:

- ensure the class cannot be overridden - make the class `final`, or use static factories and keep constructors private
- make fields `private` and `final`
- force callers to construct an object completely in a single step, instead of using a no-argument constructor combined with subsequent calls to `setXXX` methods (that is, avoid the Java Beans convention)
- do not provide any methods which can change the state of the object in any way - not just `setXXX` methods, but any method which can change state
- if the class has any mutable object fields, then they must be defensively copied when passed between the class and its caller

Comment: + add a security manager do disable changing the accessible flag by using reflection!

Comment: One more thing: make sure to make defensive copies of any mutable arguments in the constructors.  This is covered in Effective Java, 2nd Ed., item #15

Comment: Ahh yes I just looked it up item #15->5 but the actual point is made in item #39 for constructors and item #76 for `readObject` methods

Answer (score 2):

The private field can't be accessed by sub class's overridden methods...So there is no way the sub class methods change the private field of super class...Then what is the use of making the immutable class as final?

Answer (score 0):

Final keywords prevents the other classes to inherit it. Final keyword doesn't make it immutable but there are such condition as making the instance class members private as well final and by using getters and not using setters

Answer (score 0):

A final immutable classes cannot be mutated. Here below it shows a non-final immutable class being mutated:

```
// a class not intended to be mutated 
public class GoodClass{

   private String name;

   public GoodClass() {
       this.name = "Good Class Neme";
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }
}

public class BadClass extends GoodClass {

   private String name;

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   // mutating state
   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
}
```