# Deserialization of serialized final class using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have following value holder class for users:

```
package entities;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import org.immutables.value.Value;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

@Value.Immutable
@JsonSerialize(as = ImmutableUser.class)
@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutableUser.class)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
public interface User {

    String getUsername();
    String getEmail();
    @Nullable String getPassword();
    @Nullable String getEncodedPassword();
}
```

Immutable final implementation of this value holder is being generated during compilation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("all")
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
@Generated({"Immutables.generator", "User"})
@Immutable
public final class ImmutableUser implements User {
```

Serialized instance of Immutable

```
{"@class":"entities.ImmutableUser$Json","username":"testuser","email":"123@gmail.com","password":null,"encodedPassword":null}
```

The problem is that deserialization of this JSON fails with following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class entities.ImmutableUser$Json is not assignable to entities.User
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType._assertSubclass(JavaType.java:466)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType.narrowBy(JavaType.java:149)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.constructSpecializedType(TypeFactory.java:315)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.ClassNameIdResolver._typeFromId(ClassNameIdResolver.java:64)
    ... 38 more
```

Why does `@class` property in JSON for serialized instance have value `"entities.ImmutableUser$Json"` instead of `"entities.ImmutableUser"`? Is it because of fact that the class is `final`?
Is there any other way to serialize such classes and to avoid problems during deserialization?

Comment: Have you tried removing `final`?  Declaring the class `final` does not make instances of the class immutable.  See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630321/are-all-final-class-immutable

Comment: @Paul The final class is being generated by third party library so I just cannot remove final modifier from it.

Comment: see here.. this is a great link.. http://programmerbruce.blogspot.ch/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html

Comment: @awsome thanks, i've seen this link. Unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Found out that the problem was caused by generated class. Turns out the such classes should be marshaled using specific classes: https://immutables.github.io/site1.x/json.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http://immutables.github.io/site1.x/json.html is referring to the older version of documentation and is quite irrelevant if you use *Immutables* v2.0 and up. In your case you're facing an already fixed issue (similar to https://github.com/immutables/immutables/issues/175). Try upgrading to *Immutables* v2.1 to get it resolved.

In nutshell, Jackson have feature annotation `@JsonValue` to substitute object during serialization. Unfortunately as we found out that it does not play well with other functionality as `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes`. See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/937.

Version 2.1 of *Immutables* no longer used `@JsonValue`, so it should work now. If not, please report it as a bug to https://github.com/immutables/immutables/issues

Comment: Thanks, upgrading to version 2.1 has helped.

Answer (score 1):

> Found out that the problem was caused by generated class. Turns out
>   that such classes should be marshaled using specific classes:
>   immutables.github.io/site1.x/json.html